# Exibindo dados com React aparece no console mas não consigo passar pra exibir

Tags: node.js, react, react-hooks

Olá, estou com um projeto em React me retornando esse erro "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import api from '../../services/api'
import EventCard from '../../components/EventCard';

function HomePage() {

    const [listEvents, setListEvents] = useState();
    console.log(listEvents);

    useEffect(()=>{
        api.get('/events').then(response => {
            setListEvents(response.data);
        });
    },[])

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Home Page</h1>
            <a href="/login">Login</a>
            {typeof listEvents !== "undefined" && listEvents.map((value)=>{
                return <EventCard key={value.id}></EventCard>;
                })
            }
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default HomePage;
```

O EventCard é só um h1 por enquanto

```
import React from "react";

export default function EventCard (){
    return <h1>Card</h1>
}
```

No banco tem 4 eventos cadastrados, mas o resultado só está exibindo 2 vezes também.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde estou errando ? Obrigado

Comment: O Warning está ocorrendo porque você não está utilizando a props key que você passou para o componente EventCard, o H1 não está utilizado a props. Quanto ao fato de mostrar dois registros ao invés de 4, você precisa dar uma olhada no retorno de sua API (o response.data)

Comment: Ali no value.id não estou passando o valor ?

Comment: Ali no console log dá pra ver o array com 4 registros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado aos que comentaram mas consegui resolver de outra forma, vou deixar o código novo como resposta.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import EventCard from '../../components/EventCard';
import { listEvents } from '../../services/api';

function HomePage() {

    const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => { 
            const response = await listEvents();
            setEvents(response.data[0]);
            setLoading(false)
        })();
    }, []);

    if (loading) {
        return <div>Carregando...</div>
    }   

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Home Page</h1>
            <a href="/login">Login</a>

            {
                events.map((event, index) => (
                    <EventCard 
                        index={index} 
                        titulo={event.evento_titulo} 
                        cidade={event.evento_cidade}>
                    </EventCard>
                ))
            }
            

        </div>
    )
}

export default HomePage;
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro ocorre porque de fato nao existe a key passada. Pelo print que enviou, o campo `'id'` passado na key nao existe, a api retorna o atributo `'evento_id'`, logo, a key nao encontra o objeto e repete a key gerando o erro.

```
{typeof listEvents !== "undefined" && listEvents.map(value => (
  <EventCard key={value.evento_id} />;
 ))}
```

Mais ou menos assim, deve resolver seu problema

Comment: Eu já tinha tentado dessa forma amigo, consegui alterando a forma de exibir, vou anexar como resposta